# LXC broken after router malfunction

Tags: lxc, lxd

A few days ago my router had a bit of a funny turn. All its lights said it was fine, and devices could connect to wifi, but it provided no internet connectivity, no device-to-device connectivity on the LAN (even wired), and I couldn't access its webadmin page. After a couple of hours and a couple of resets, it worked fine again.

BUT since then, my LXC install is horribly broken. Even a simple `lxc list` results in `Error: Get "http://unix.socket/1.0": dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: connection refused`

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I wasn't running anything particularly heavy on LXC; mainly a LAMP stack with some local services.

Any thoughts? I'm very much not an LXC expert, and don't really know where to start.